# TypeError: expected a character buffer object when writing parsing result

Tags: python, html-parsing

```
import requests
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        return data

def criapagina():
    r = requests.get('http://shadowcores.twifysoft.net/character.php?name=Sonda+Aquatica')
    fo = open('teste.txt', 'w')
    fo.write(r.content)
    print fo.readline
    fo.close()

def lepagina():
    fo = open('teste.txt', 'r+')
    for line in fo:
        parser = MyHTMLParser()
        fo.write(parser.feed(line))
        fo.close()


lepagina()
```

I want to parse the html and write on the file to after read the correct lines for example Name: Sonda Level: bla bla
but i cant even save this on file, cause i got the error: TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: Your reading and writing at the same time is going to fail; you make no attempt to control *where* in `teste.txt` you are writing the parser result. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Moreover, did you check what `parser.feed()` **returns**? It is not a string, that is for sure.

Comment: You are not ever calling `criapagina`; `requests` is not being used at all here.

Comment: i previous have called the criapagina :P so i allready have the teste.txt

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because `HTMLParser.feed()` returns `None`; you cannot write `None` to a file:

```
>>> open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w').write(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Your attempt to read and write to `teste.txt` will otherwise fail; you should **not** both treat the file object as an iterator (`for line in fo`) and expect to be able to write to the file. The file iterator uses a read-ahead buffer and you have *no idea* where your write is going to end up in the file.

It is otherwise entirely unclear as to what you are trying to do. Normally, you'd write a custom subclass of the `HTMLParser` class that collects data in instance attributes. You then call `.feed()`, after which you collect whatever you wanted from those attributes.

You may be better off using an easier API for HTML like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), which doesn't require you to create a parser subclass and is much easier to use when it comes to simple HTML extraction tasks.

Comment: As martin said, the return type is none, however you might try redirecting the system out put to the file which will work for sure, otherwise suggest you to use Beautiful Soup :)